# Get transaction details in real time, Paypal

Tags: api, paypal

I am creating a website and instead of using a fully featured shopping cart I want to use the Paypal API to "automate" some functionality.

By that, the user clicks on the "buy now" button goes and makes payment to paypal, and I want them to be redirected back to my site so I can process some info for my database. I looked into IPN  but it seems like an overkill. Is there any simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at either IPN or Express Checkout.

If you are using web standard payments it is important to note that a customer does not have to return to your page, once they hit pay on the Paypal site - the transaction is complete. Hence relying on them to return to your page to do a database update is a bad idea. This is where IPN comes into play.

Express Checkout gets around this by allowing the customer to authorize on Paypal and complete a transaction on your site. Passing the data directly to your site once the transaction is complete.

Comment: I will look into both because i had not considered the fact that they don't have to come back, which a big deal. Thanks

Comment: IPN is still very useful when working with Express Checkout.  For example, the Express Checkout process could completely successfully, but the payment might be pending because of an e-check, fraud filters, etc.  IPN would send a notification about the pending payment, and then another once that payment clears (or fails) so you can process it accordingly.  You would also need IPN to handle recurring payments transactions setup through Express Checkout.  Express Checkout is definitely recommended over standard, though, since it does make it back to the site, which allows you to handle Analytics